# одеть или надеть

Tags: как

одеть/надеть памперс на ребенка

Comment: Эмилия, попытайтесь сами найти ответ на вопрос. Это очень просто сделать.

Comment: просто очень важно, спор возник и непонятно какой вариант верен теперь

Comment: Это очень простой вопрос. А возникает он от массового неправильного употребления этих глаголов. Посмотрите здесь, например: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/trudnosti?id=36_119&layout=item А еще есть такая запоминалка: *Надеть одежду. Одеть Надежду*.